# How Get llvm Library in Go?

Tags: go, llvm

My OS is GNU/Ubuntu 16.10- 64bit.

i also report this to GoLang.

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19444

### $ go get llvm.org/llvm/bindings/go/llvm

```
package llvm.org/llvm/bindings/go/llvm: unrecognized import path "llvm.org/llvm/bindings/go/llvm" (parse https://llvm.org/llvm/bindings/go/llvm?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
```

### $ go get llvm.org/llvm/bindings

```
package llvm.org/llvm/bindings: unrecognized import path "llvm.org/llvm/bindings" (parse https://llvm.org/llvm/bindings?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
```

so `go get` say not parse https://llvm.org/llvm/bindings?go-get=1

in browser also `https://llvm.org/` not open.(HTTPS)

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at llvm.org Port 443
```

but `http://llvm.org` is good.(HTTP)

how can get this libs for GoLang?

==================

Try `github.com/go-llvm/llgo` :

```
guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo$ ./llgo-go.sh build
can't load package: package github.com/go-llvm/llgo: no buildable Go source files in /home/guest/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo
guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo$ ./llgo-go.sh install
can't load package: package github.com/go-llvm/llgo: no buildable Go source files in /home/guest/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo
guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo$ ./llgo-go.sh install
can't load package: package github.com/go-llvm/llgo: no buildable Go source files in /home/guest/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo
guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo$ make
./update_clang.sh
can't load package: package llvm.org/llvm/bindings/go/llvm: cannot find package "llvm.org/llvm/bindings/go/llvm" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.8/src/llvm.org/llvm/bindings/go/llvm (from $GOROOT)
    /home/guest/go/src/llvm.org/llvm/bindings/go/llvm (from $GOPATH)
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'workdir/.update-clang-stamp' failed
make: *** [workdir/.update-clang-stamp] Error 1
guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo$ export PATH=/path/to/gcc-inst/bin:$PATH
guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/gcc-inst/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo$ export CC=`which gcc`
guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo$ export CXX=`which g++`
guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo$ export LIBGO_CFLAGS=--gcc-toolchain=/path/to/gcc-inst
guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo$ go get -d github.com/go-llvm/llgo/cmd/gllgo
package llvm.org/llvm/bindings/go/llvm: unrecognized import path "llvm.org/llvm/bindings/go/llvm" (parse https://llvm.org/llvm/bindings/go/llvm?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
package golang.org/x/tools/go/exact: cannot find package "golang.org/x/tools/go/exact" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.8/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/exact (from $GOROOT)
    /home/guest/go/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/exact (from $GOPATH)
package golang.org/x/tools/go/gccgoimporter: cannot find package "golang.org/x/tools/go/gccgoimporter" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.8/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/gccgoimporter (from $GOROOT)
    /home/guest/go/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/gccgoimporter (from $GOPATH)
package golang.org/x/tools/go/importer: cannot find package "golang.org/x/tools/go/importer" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.8/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/importer (from $GOROOT)
    /home/guest/go/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/importer (from $GOPATH)
guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo$ $GOPATH/src/llvm.org/llvm/bindings/go/build.sh -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=host
bash: /home/guest/go/src/llvm.org/llvm/bindings/go/build.sh: No such file or directory
guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llgo$
```

---

```
$ go version
go version go1.8 linux/amd64
$ cmake -version
cmake version 3.8.20170216-gb9229

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

---

guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm$ ./update_llvm.sh

```
+ llvm_components=all-targets analysis asmparser asmprinter bitreader bitwriter codegen core debuginfo executionengine instrumentation interpreter ipo irreader linker mc mcjit objcarcopts option profiledata scalaropts support target 
+ dirname ./update_llvm.sh
+ gollvmdir=.
+ grep run_update_llvm_sh_to_get_revision_ ./llvm_dep.go
+ sed -E -e s/.*run_update_llvm_sh_to_get_revision_([0-9]+.*)/\1/g
+ llvmrev=218171
+ workdir=./workdir
+ llvmdir=./workdir/llvm
+ llvm_builddir=./workdir/llvm_build
+ mkdir -p ./workdir
+ svn co -r 218171 https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk ./workdir/llvm
Checked out revision 218171.
+ mkdir -p ./workdir/llvm_build
+ cmake_flags=../llvm 
+ llvm_config=./workdir/llvm_build/bin/llvm-config
+ which ninja
+ test -n /usr/bin/ninja
+ cd ./workdir/llvm_build
+ cmake -G Ninja ../llvm
-- Target triple: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
-- Native target architecture is X86
-- Threads enabled.
-- Doxygen disabled.
-- Sphinx disabled.
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/modules/HandleLLVMOptions.cmake:131 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "C_SUPPORTS_FPIC" will no longer be dereferenced when
  the policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior
  will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/HandleLLVMOptions.cmake:148 (add_flag_or_print_warning)
  CMakeLists.txt:315 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Building with -fPIC
-- Constructing LLVMBuild project information
-- Targeting AArch64
-- Targeting ARM
-- Targeting CppBackend
-- Targeting Hexagon
-- Targeting Mips
-- Targeting MSP430
-- Targeting NVPTX
-- Targeting PowerPC
-- Targeting R600
-- Targeting Sparc
-- Targeting SystemZ
-- Targeting X86
-- Targeting XCore
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/guest/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm/workdir/llvm_build
+ ninja -C ./workdir/llvm_build llvm-config
ninja: Entering directory `./workdir/llvm_build'
[2/2] Linking CXX executable bin/llvm-config
+ ./workdir/llvm_build/bin/llvm-config --libs all-targets analysis asmparser asmprinter bitreader bitwriter codegen core debuginfo executionengine instrumentation interpreter ipo irreader linker mc mcjit objcarcopts option profiledata scalaropts support target
+ sed -e s/-l//g
+ llvm_buildtargets=LLVMOption LLVMObjCARCOpts LLVMMCJIT LLVMRuntimeDyld LLVMLinker LLVMIRReader LLVMipo LLVMVectorize LLVMInterpreter LLVMInstrumentation LLVMExecutionEngine LLVMDebugInfo LLVMBitWriter LLVMAsmParser LLVMXCoreDisassembler LLVMXCoreCodeGen LLVMXCoreDesc LLVMXCoreInfo LLVMXCoreAsmPrinter LLVMX86Disassembler LLVMX86AsmParser LLVMX86CodeGen LLVMX86Desc LLVMX86Info LLVMX86AsmPrinter LLVMX86Utils LLVMSystemZDisassembler LLVMSystemZCodeGen LLVMSystemZAsmParser LLVMSystemZDesc LLVMSystemZInfo LLVMSystemZAsmPrinter LLVMSparcDisassembler LLVMSparcCodeGen LLVMSparcAsmParser LLVMSparcDesc LLVMSparcInfo LLVMSparcAsmPrinter LLVMR600CodeGen LLVMR600Desc LLVMR600Info LLVMR600AsmPrinter LLVMPowerPCDisassembler LLVMPowerPCCodeGen LLVMPowerPCAsmParser LLVMPowerPCDesc LLVMPowerPCInfo LLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter LLVMNVPTXCodeGen LLVMNVPTXDesc LLVMNVPTXInfo LLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter LLVMMSP430CodeGen LLVMMSP430Desc LLVMMSP430Info LLVMMSP430AsmPrinter LLVMMipsDisassembler LLVMMipsCodeGen LLVMMipsAsmParser LLVMMipsDesc LLVMMipsInfo LLVMMipsAsmPrinter LLVMHexagonCodeGen LLVMHexagonAsmPrinter LLVMHexagonDesc LLVMHexagonInfo LLVMCppBackendCodeGen LLVMCppBackendInfo LLVMARMDisassembler LLVMARMCodeGen LLVMARMAsmParser LLVMARMDesc LLVMARMInfo LLVMARMAsmPrinter LLVMAArch64Disassembler LLVMMCDisassembler LLVMAArch64CodeGen LLVMSelectionDAG LLVMAsmPrinter LLVMCodeGen LLVMScalarOpts LLVMProfileData LLVMObject LLVMBitReader LLVMInstCombine LLVMTransformUtils LLVMipa LLVMAnalysis LLVMTarget LLVMCore LLVMAArch64AsmParser LLVMMCParser LLVMAArch64Desc LLVMAArch64Info LLVMAArch64AsmPrinter LLVMMC LLVMAArch64Utils LLVMSupport
+ ninja -C ./workdir/llvm_build LLVMOption LLVMObjCARCOpts LLVMMCJIT LLVMRuntimeDyld LLVMLinker LLVMIRReader LLVMipo LLVMVectorize LLVMInterpreter LLVMInstrumentation LLVMExecutionEngine LLVMDebugInfo LLVMBitWriter LLVMAsmParser LLVMXCoreDisassembler LLVMXCoreCodeGen LLVMXCoreDesc LLVMXCoreInfo LLVMXCoreAsmPrinter LLVMX86Disassembler LLVMX86AsmParser LLVMX86CodeGen LLVMX86Desc LLVMX86Info LLVMX86AsmPrinter LLVMX86Utils LLVMSystemZDisassembler LLVMSystemZCodeGen LLVMSystemZAsmParser LLVMSystemZDesc LLVMSystemZInfo LLVMSystemZAsmPrinter LLVMSparcDisassembler LLVMSparcCodeGen LLVMSparcAsmParser LLVMSparcDesc LLVMSparcInfo LLVMSparcAsmPrinter LLVMR600CodeGen LLVMR600Desc LLVMR600Info LLVMR600AsmPrinter LLVMPowerPCDisassembler LLVMPowerPCCodeGen LLVMPowerPCAsmParser LLVMPowerPCDesc LLVMPowerPCInfo LLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter LLVMNVPTXCodeGen LLVMNVPTXDesc LLVMNVPTXInfo LLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter LLVMMSP430CodeGen LLVMMSP430Desc LLVMMSP430Info LLVMMSP430AsmPrinter LLVMMipsDisassembler LLVMMipsCodeGen LLVMMipsAsmParser LLVMMipsDesc LLVMMipsInfo LLVMMipsAsmPrinter LLVMHexagonCodeGen LLVMHexagonAsmPrinter LLVMHexagonDesc LLVMHexagonInfo LLVMCppBackendCodeGen LLVMCppBackendInfo LLVMARMDisassembler LLVMARMCodeGen LLVMARMAsmParser LLVMARMDesc LLVMARMInfo LLVMARMAsmPrinter LLVMAArch64Disassembler LLVMMCDisassembler LLVMAArch64CodeGen LLVMSelectionDAG LLVMAsmPrinter LLVMCodeGen LLVMScalarOpts LLVMProfileData LLVMObject LLVMBitReader LLVMInstCombine LLVMTransformUtils LLVMipa LLVMAnalysis LLVMTarget LLVMCore LLVMAArch64AsmParser LLVMMCParser LLVMAArch64Desc LLVMAArch64Info LLVMAArch64AsmPrinter LLVMMC LLVMAArch64Utils LLVMSupport FileCheck
ninja: Entering directory `./workdir/llvm_build'
ninja: no work to do.
+ ./workdir/llvm_build/bin/llvm-config --version
+ llvm_version=3.6.0svn
+ ./workdir/llvm_build/bin/llvm-config --cppflags
+ llvm_cflags=-I/home/guest/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm/workdir/llvm/include -I/home/guest/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm/workdir/llvm_build/include    -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
+ uname
+ [ Linux == Darwin ]
./update_llvm.sh: 59: [: Linux: unexpected operator
+ ./workdir/llvm_build/bin/llvm-config --ldflags
+ ./workdir/llvm_build/bin/llvm-config --libdir
+ ./workdir/llvm_build/bin/llvm-config --libs all-targets analysis asmparser asmprinter bitreader bitwriter codegen core debuginfo executionengine instrumentation interpreter ipo irreader linker mc mcjit objcarcopts option profiledata scalaropts support target
+ ./workdir/llvm_build/bin/llvm-config --system-libs
+ llvm_ldflags=-L/home/guest/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm/workdir/llvm_build//lib  -Wl,-rpath,/home/guest/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm/workdir/llvm_build//lib -lLLVMOption -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMMCJIT -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMLinker -lLLVMIRReader -lLLVMipo -lLLVMVectorize -lLLVMInterpreter -lLLVMInstrumentation -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMDebugInfo -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMAsmParser -lLLVMXCoreDisassembler -lLLVMXCoreCodeGen -lLLVMXCoreDesc -lLLVMXCoreInfo -lLLVMXCoreAsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMSystemZDisassembler -lLLVMSystemZCodeGen -lLLVMSystemZAsmParser -lLLVMSystemZDesc -lLLVMSystemZInfo -lLLVMSystemZAsmPrinter -lLLVMSparcDisassembler -lLLVMSparcCodeGen -lLLVMSparcAsmParser -lLLVMSparcDesc -lLLVMSparcInfo -lLLVMSparcAsmPrinter -lLLVMR600CodeGen -lLLVMR600Desc -lLLVMR600Info -lLLVMR600AsmPrinter -lLLVMPowerPCDisassembler -lLLVMPowerPCCodeGen -lLLVMPowerPCAsmParser -lLLVMPowerPCDesc -lLLVMPowerPCInfo -lLLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter -lLLVMNVPTXCodeGen -lLLVMNVPTXDesc -lLLVMNVPTXInfo -lLLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter -lLLVMMSP430CodeGen -lLLVMMSP430Desc -lLLVMMSP430Info -lLLVMMSP430AsmPrinter -lLLVMMipsDisassembler -lLLVMMipsCodeGen -lLLVMMipsAsmParser -lLLVMMipsDesc -lLLVMMipsInfo -lLLVMMipsAsmPrinter -lLLVMHexagonCodeGen -lLLVMHexagonAsmPrinter -lLLVMHexagonDesc -lLLVMHexagonInfo -lLLVMCppBackendCodeGen -lLLVMCppBackendInfo -lLLVMARMDisassembler -lLLVMARMCodeGen -lLLVMARMAsmParser -lLLVMARMDesc -lLLVMARMInfo -lLLVMARMAsmPrinter -lLLVMAArch64Disassembler -lLLVMMCDisassembler -lLLVMAArch64CodeGen -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMProfileData -lLLVMObject -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMCore -lLLVMAArch64AsmParser -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMAArch64Desc -lLLVMAArch64Info -lLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter -lLLVMMC -lLLVMAArch64Utils -lLLVMSupport -lrt -ldl -ltinfo -latomic -lpthread -lz
+ sed -e s#@LLVM_REVISION@#218171#g; s#@LLVM_CFLAGS@#-I/home/guest/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm/workdir/llvm/include -I/home/guest/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm/workdir/llvm_build/include    -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS#g;         s#@LLVM_LDFLAGS@#-L/home/guest/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm/workdir/llvm_build//lib  -Wl,-rpath,/home/guest/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm/workdir/llvm_build//lib -lLLVMOption -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMMCJIT -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMLinker -lLLVMIRReader -lLLVMipo -lLLVMVectorize -lLLVMInterpreter -lLLVMInstrumentation -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMDebugInfo -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMAsmParser -lLLVMXCoreDisassembler -lLLVMXCoreCodeGen -lLLVMXCoreDesc -lLLVMXCoreInfo -lLLVMXCoreAsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMSystemZDisassembler -lLLVMSystemZCodeGen -lLLVMSystemZAsmParser -lLLVMSystemZDesc -lLLVMSystemZInfo -lLLVMSystemZAsmPrinter -lLLVMSparcDisassembler -lLLVMSparcCodeGen -lLLVMSparcAsmParser -lLLVMSparcDesc -lLLVMSparcInfo -lLLVMSparcAsmPrinter -lLLVMR600CodeGen -lLLVMR600Desc -lLLVMR600Info -lLLVMR600AsmPrinter -lLLVMPowerPCDisassembler -lLLVMPowerPCCodeGen -lLLVMPowerPCAsmParser -lLLVMPowerPCDesc -lLLVMPowerPCInfo -lLLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter -lLLVMNVPTXCodeGen -lLLVMNVPTXDesc -lLLVMNVPTXInfo -lLLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter -lLLVMMSP430CodeGen -lLLVMMSP430Desc -lLLVMMSP430Info -lLLVMMSP430AsmPrinter -lLLVMMipsDisassembler -lLLVMMipsCodeGen -lLLVMMipsAsmParser -lLLVMMipsDesc -lLLVMMipsInfo -lLLVMMipsAsmPrinter -lLLVMHexagonCodeGen -lLLVMHexagonAsmPrinter -lLLVMHexagonDesc -lLLVMHexagonInfo -lLLVMCppBackendCodeGen -lLLVMCppBackendInfo -lLLVMARMDisassembler -lLLVMARMCodeGen -lLLVMARMAsmParser -lLLVMARMDesc -lLLVMARMInfo -lLLVMARMAsmPrinter -lLLVMAArch64Disassembler -lLLVMMCDisassembler -lLLVMAArch64CodeGen -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMProfileData -lLLVMObject -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMCore -lLLVMAArch64AsmParser -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMAArch64Desc -lLLVMAArch64Info -lLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter -lLLVMMC -lLLVMAArch64Utils -lLLVMSupport -lrt -ldl -ltinfo -latomic -lpthread -lz#g ./llvm_config.go.in
+ printf package llvm\n\nconst Version = "%s"\n 3.6.0svn
```

guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm/examples$ cd factorial

guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm/examples/factorial$ ls
    factorial  factorial.go

guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm/examples/factorial$ go build factorial.go

guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm/examples/factorial$ ./factorial

```
; ModuleID = 'fac_module'

define i32 @fac(i32) {
entry:
  %cmptmp = icmp eq i32 %0, 0
  br i1 %cmptmp, label %end, label %iffalse

iffalse:                                          ; preds = %entry
  %subtmp = add i32 %0, -1
  %calltmp = call i32 @fac(i32 %subtmp)
  %multmp = mul i32 %calltmp, %0
  br label %end

end:                                              ; preds = %entry, %iffalse
  %result = phi i32 [ %multmp, %iffalse ], [ 1, %entry ]
  ret i32 %result
}
-----------------------------------------
Running fac(10) with JIT...
Result: 3628800
DONE
```

---

```
guest@system:~$ go get llvm.org/llvm.v36/bindings/go/llvm
package llvm.org/llvm.v36/bindings/go/llvm: unrecognized import path "llvm.org/llvm.v36/bindings/go/llvm" (parse https://llvm.org/llvm.v36/bindings/go/llvm?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
guest@system:~$ go get -d llvm.org/llvm.v36/bindings/go/llvm
package llvm.org/llvm.v36/bindings/go/llvm: unrecognized import path "llvm.org/llvm.v36/bindings/go/llvm" (parse https://llvm.org/llvm.v36/bindings/go/llvm?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
```

---

```
$ which llvm-config
/usr/bin/llvm-config

guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/go-llvm/llvm/workdir/llvm_build/bin$ ls
FileCheck  llvm-config  llvm-lit  llvm-tblgen
```

---

guest@system:~/go/src/github.com/axw/llgo$ ./update_third_party.sh

github.com/axw/llgo$ ./update_third_party.sh

```
Cloning into '/tmp/update_third_party.auPNC9/gofrontend'...
remote: Sending approximately 92.68 MiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 3087, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (69/69)
remote: Total 33940 (delta 26755), reused 33933 (delta 26755)
Receiving objects: 100% (33940/33940), 92.79 MiB | 60.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (26755/26755), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Note: checking out '81eb6a3f425b2158c67ee32c0cc973a72ce9d6be'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 81eb6a3... runtime: don't overallocate in select code
patching file libgo/runtime/chan.goc
patching file libgo/runtime/chan.h
patching file libgo/runtime/heapdump.c
patching file libgo/runtime/malloc.goc
patching file libgo/runtime/malloc.h
Hunk #1 succeeded at 392 (offset 2 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 403 (offset 2 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 460 (offset 2 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 478 (offset 2 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 507 (offset 2 lines).
patching file libgo/runtime/mcache.c
patching file libgo/runtime/mcentral.c
patching file libgo/runtime/mgc0.c
Hunk #3 succeeded at 1380 (offset 2 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 1390 (offset 2 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 1804 (offset 2 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 2151 (offset 4 lines).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 2428 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 2443 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 2451 (offset 5 lines).
patching file libgo/runtime/mheap.c
patching file libgo/runtime/netpoll.goc
patching file libgo/runtime/proc.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 326 (offset 24 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 809 (offset 100 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 820 (offset 100 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 847 (offset 100 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 855 (offset 100 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 864 (offset 100 lines).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 881 (offset 100 lines).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 894 (offset 100 lines).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 933 (offset 100 lines).
Hunk #10 succeeded at 953 (offset 100 lines).
Hunk #11 succeeded at 987 (offset 100 lines).
Hunk #12 succeeded at 1011 (offset 100 lines).
Hunk #13 succeeded at 1452 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #14 succeeded at 1481 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #15 succeeded at 1525 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #16 succeeded at 1618 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #17 succeeded at 1673 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #18 succeeded at 1709 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #19 succeeded at 1730 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #20 succeeded at 1749 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #21 succeeded at 1794 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #22 succeeded at 1832 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #23 succeeded at 1928 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #24 succeeded at 2031 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #25 succeeded at 2159 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #26 succeeded at 2184 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #27 succeeded at 2192 (offset 106 lines).
Hunk #28 succeeded at 2484 (offset 119 lines).
Hunk #29 succeeded at 2595 (offset 119 lines).
Hunk #30 succeeded at 2627 (offset 119 lines).
Hunk #31 succeeded at 2657 (offset 119 lines).
Hunk #32 succeeded at 2682 (offset 119 lines).
Hunk #33 succeeded at 2826 (offset 119 lines).
Hunk #34 succeeded at 2906 (offset 126 lines).
Hunk #35 succeeded at 3044 (offset 126 lines).
Hunk #36 succeeded at 3080 (offset 126 lines).
Hunk #37 succeeded at 3112 (offset 126 lines).
Hunk #38 succeeded at 3268 (offset 126 lines).
Hunk #39 succeeded at 3422 (offset 126 lines).
patching file libgo/runtime/runtime.h
patching file libgo/runtime/sema.goc
patching file libgo/runtime/sigqueue.goc
patching file libgo/runtime/time.goc
patching file libgo/Makefile.am
Hunk #1 succeeded at 4139 (offset 401 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 4246 (offset 409 lines).
patching file libgo/Makefile.in
Hunk #1 succeeded at 2433 (offset 221 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 2540 (offset 229 lines).
patching file libgo/go/runtime/mfinal_test.go
Hunk #1 succeeded at 65 (offset 3 lines).
cp: cannot stat '../../cmake/config.guess': No such file or directory
```

how can fix?

Comment: `llgo` has installation instructions available at https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llgo/trunk/README.TXT; did you go through those, and if so, which issues did you encounter?

Comment: Please again check new update of question.